# How can I add a class to every 4th - 1 element?

Tags: jquery, modulo

Don't ask why but I need to add class zebra to the `<li>` elements with the content next to them. This is as far as I've got, but I'm not sure what calculation to use:

```
$("li").each(function(index){
    if(index % ??? == 0) {  // <-- not sure what to put here

    }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li> <!-- add the zebra class here -->
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li> <!-- add the zebra class here -->
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li> <!-- add the zebra class here -->
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Normal zebra or just on those who have content? Please elaborate your question a bit more!

Comment: You show 3, 4, 4. Which is it, 3 or 4? And what is index? Remember, modulo is the remainder. So, if 3 % 1 = 2, 3 % 2 = 1, 3 % 3 = 0

Comment: Just where there is comment. The first zebra at index 2 and then a zebra after 3 indexes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector can accept an equation, and it solves your problem perfectly:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(4n+3)').addClass("zebra").text("Here");
```

Selects every 4th `li` starting at 3 onwards, `:nth-child(4n-1)` would also work (every 4th-1 element).  No `each()` or modulo necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvPhe/ - Example based on your sample input, the *zebra* class is added along with the text *"Here"*.

Comment: ++ Much more succinct than the other answers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about the nth-child selector. In my case though it's (4n+2)

Comment: @chchrist: It's a cool selector :-) the example you gave in the question is (4n+3), so I just worked with that (check out the fiddle link).

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you want the 3rd, 7th, 11th, ... with class "zebra":

```
$("li").each(function(index,item){

if((index+2)%4 == 0) {
  $(item).addClass("zebra");
}

});
```

**EDIT**: Check out Andy's answer. Much better than mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

The period is 4 so the modulo should be 4.
However it is offset by two so you need to add 2 to the index:

```
if ((index + 2) % 4 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (index % 4 == 2)
```

is what I think you're looking for.

In your example, you have the 3rd, 7th and 10th elements selected.