# Add a CSS Class alternating every 2 rows

Tags: jquery

I have a table like so:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
</table>
```

​
I want to add a CSS Class `alt` after every 2 rows, so for example I'll have a sequence of 2 white rows, 2 red rows, 2 white rows, 2 red rows and so on. Is this possible with JQuery?

Comment: See this related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068480/how-can-i-add-a-class-to-every-4th-1-element

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794564/alternating-table-row-color-but-with-2-rows-of-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/okahax/edit#javascript,html

```
var t = 0;
$("table tr").each(function (i, n)
{
    if (t < 2) 
    {$(this).css('background-color','red');

    }
    else if (t < 4)
    { 
        $(this).css('background-color','white');

    }
  t++;
  if (t==4) t=0;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$('tr:nth-child(4n),tr:nth-child(4n-1)').addClass('alt');
```

This uses the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) with an appropriate equation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cnQNx/

Or:

```
$('tr:nth-child(4n)').prev().andSelf().addClass('alt');
```