# Alternating Row Colors with Hidden Rows

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my project I'm showing contact information in a table. By default I'm showing the core information for the person in a row in a table. Clicking a button expands the next row for more detailed information.

In my table I want to have alternating colored rows in the default view where all of the detail rows are collapsed. When a record is expanded to show the second row with the detailed information I want the row to be the same color as it's parent since they're all information for the same person.

Right now in the default view each row is the same color and the detail view rows are the alternating color which makes for a confusing user interface.

Here is my code:

HTML/Ruby for the page:

```
<%- model_class = Person -%>
    <div class="page-header detail">
        <h4>Search Results</h4>
    </div>

    <table class="table detail table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <% @people.each do |person| %>
            <tr class="parent">
                <td><%= image_tag "photo-1.png", :height => '32', :width => '40' %></td>
                <td><%= link_to person.lname + ", " + person.fname, person %><br> <%= person.ntid %><br>

                    <td><%= number_to_phone(person.phone, :area_code => true) %><br><%= mail_to person.email %></td>
                    <td>Suite: <%= person.suite %><br>Column: <%= person.column %></td>

                    <td><!--  lightbox code -->
                        <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#<%= person.id %>Lightbox"><%= image_tag "map_icon1.png", :width => '32' %> </a>
                        <div id="<%= person.id %>Lightbox" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class='lightbox-header'>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="lightbox" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class='lightbox-content'>
                                <%=image_tag person.map %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end lightbox code -->
                        </td>

                        <!-- Dropdown button -->
                        <td><a class="dropme" href="#<%= person.id %>"> <button class="btn btn-info btn-small">
                            <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
                        </button></a></td>

                    <!-- end dropdown button -->


                    <tr class="child">
                        <td></td> 
                        <td>Title: <%= person.title %><br>Department: <%= person.department %><br>Manager: <%= person.manager %><br>Direct Reports: <%= person.direct_report %></td>
                        <td>Mobile: <%= number_to_phone(person.mobile, :area_code => true) %><br>FAX: <%= number_to_phone(person.fax, :area_code => true) %><br>Pager: <%= number_to_phone(person.pager, :area_code => true) %></td><td><%= person.company %><br><%= person.office %><br><%= person.address %><br><%= person.city %>, <%= person.state %> <%= person.zipcode %><br><%= person.country %></td>
                        <td><td> <!-- empty cell to have things line up  -->
                        <td><td> <!-- empty cell to have things line up  -->
                        <td><td> <!-- empty cell to have things line up  -->
                    </tr>


                <!-- <td>
                <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                edit_person_path(person), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
                <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                person_path(person),
                :method => :delete,
                :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
                </td> -->
            <!-- </tr> -->
            <% end %>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My Javascript for expanding and collapsing the rows is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table.detail').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this);
            $('tbody tr .dropme').click(function(event){
                var $tgt=$(event.target);
                event.stopPropagation();
                var closestRow=$tgt.closest('tr');
                // closestRow.siblings('.child').eq(0).toggle();
                closestRow.next().toggle('slow');
                var pcolor=closestRow.css("background-color");
                closestRow.next().css('background-color', pcolor);
            });
        });
    });
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just apply the :even or :odd pseudo-selector and some CSS. http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Comment: It looks like :even and :odd would do the same thing as the bootstrap alternating theme. I need rows 1&2 to be the same color, 3&4 to be the same color...

Comment: Would you be willing switch to a tableless design?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974536/add-a-css-class-alternating-every-2-rows

Answer (score 0):

Check out rails cycle helper

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle

You'll be able to add an 'even' class to the 3rd and 4th rows.